# Dialogflow - multiple agent.add responses (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

In my fulfilment code, if I do:

```
agent.add('Hello');
agent.add('World');
```

both the console and the Google assistant will do:

> Agent: Hello
>
> Agent: World

But in the web demo and other embedded examples, it only responds:

> Agent: Hello.

How do I fix this, and get multiple responses in multiple messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this in Dialogflow, so my solution was simply:

```
var message;

message = 'Hello '
message += 'World.'

agent.add(message);
```